# PHP/MYSQL Can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I recently moved a website with a MYSQL database to a new server.
The problem is the old server was using a sub.domain name and the config file still points to the sub.domain.  I've tried many approaches, but can't get the database to connect.

I believe the issue is that the database is still trying to use the sub.domain name. instead of the new domain on the new server.  I tried removing references to: WHERE subdomain=, but i still can't connect to the database.

any help would be appreciated.  Config file info below.

```
<?php
// Database settings
$database               = array();
$database['host']       = "localhost";
$database['user']       = "***********";
$database['password']   = "***********";
$database['database']   = "***********";
#echo "<h1>".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."</h1>";die();
define('SITE_MAIN', 'dessinsllcportal.com');
if (!(mysql_connect($database['host'], $database['user'], $database['password'])))
    crash_q();
if (!(mysql_select_db($database['database'])))
    crash_q();
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $ref = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE subdomain='".$ref[0]."'";
if (($result = mysql_query($query)))
{
    $dbRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    define('FM_HOST',  $dbRow['host']);
    define('FM_FILE',  $dbRow['file']);
    define('SITE_URL', 'http://'.$dbRow['subdomain'].SITE_MAIN);
}else{
    define('FM_HOST', '');
    define('FM_FILE', '');
    define('SITE_URL', 'http://'.$dbRow['subdomain'].SITE_MAIN);
}
define('FM_USER', 'PHPuser');
define('FM_PASS', 'inter10r');
define('USER_LAYOUT', 'PHP_User');
define('SMARTY_DIR', '/var/www/clients/client120/web138/web/smarty/');
define('APP_FULL_PATH', '/var/www/clients/client120/web138/web');
```

Comment: Does your table `sites` in the MySQL have the old name?

Comment: when i try to connect i get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function crash_q() in /var/www/clients/client120/web138/web/config/config.inc on line 13

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: `$database['database']` is invalid. Make sure you put the correct value there.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it appears that you forgot to move the file that defines the function `crash_q()` or possibly accidentally removed the inclusion of the file that defined it, or possibly accidentally deleted its definition from your code. Track down where `crash_q()` is defined and make sure the definition is available in your code. If you cannot find it, you can just add

```
function crash_q()
{
  die("Fatal error:".mysql_error());
}
```

In fact, if your old `crash_q()` was not more informative, you should use this one for now to debug (but change it to log to a file instead for security reasons once everything works). Then see what the error from MySQL is and go from there.